# How to control percent in Forecast Sheet no more over 100%?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-365, microsoft-excel-2019

How to control percent in Forecast Sheet no more over 100% ?

I learn to make Forecast Sheet with percent value with link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-forecast-in-excel-for-windows-22c500da-6da7-45e5-bfdc-60a7062329fd but percent in Forecast Sheet over 100% , I have to to control percent in Forecast Sheet no more over 100% although settings any value in Forecast End.

**Example excel file** : https://github.com/doanga2007/doanga2007.github.io/raw/master/percentforecast.xlsx

**Picture describe percent in Forecast Sheet over 100% :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnaW4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good News :** I fix problem with basic solution and credit to fix problem : https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10219737842330601&set=p.10219737842330601&type=1 and https://www.snasui.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17680

1. Have forecast value (Value1 and Value2) with FORECAST.ETS formula example **=FORECAST.ETS(A5,$B$2:$B$4,$A$2:$A$4)**
2. Use Value2 * 100 / Value1 formula example **=C2*100/B2** to find Value2 % value with compare to Value1
3. Use MIN formula to control percent value **(2.)** in Sheet no more over 100% example **=MIN(100,D2)**
4. I can to insert Excel grpah instantly.

**Excel file to fix problem link :** https://github.com/doanga2007/doanga2007.github.io/raw/master/percentforecast2.xlsx

**Edit1 :** Alternative step to improve formula and credit to improve formula : https://www.wikihow.com/Run-Regression-Analysis-in-Microsoft-Excel and https://www.thepexcel.com/excel-forecast/

1. Change FORCAST.ETS formula to not dollar sign at number location example **=FORECAST.ETS(A5,$B2:$B4,$A2:$A4)** and next cell to formula is **=FORECAST.ETS(A6,$B3:$B5,$A3:$A5)**.
2. Check Regression value with step.

2.1 Click to **File** in  Ribbon Tab -> Click to **Option**

2.2 Click to **Add-in** -> Click to **Go...**

2.3 Select **Analysis ToolPak** and click to OK

2.4 Click to **Data** in Ribbon Tab -> Click to **Data Analysis**

2.5 Click to **Regression** in Analysis Tools -> Click to OK

2.6 Config Regression with image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVzzk.png and click to OK

2.7 Have Regression value

3. Change graph to Line graph type to Scatter graph type with popular to create ROC Chart.

**Excel file to improve with green tab link :** https://github.com/doanga2007/doanga2007.github.io/raw/master/percentforecast3.xlsx